# angular2 animation error while a prior animation is in progress: ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined

Tags: angular2-animation

i'm incurring:

```
ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'hasOwnProperty' of undefined
    at http://0.0.0.0:4200/vendor.bundle.js:34007:40
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at WebAnimationsPlayer.init (http://0.0.0.0:4200/vendor.bundle.js:34006:32)
    at InjectableAnimationEngine.DomAnimationEngine._queuePlayer (http://0.0.0.0:4200/vendor.bundle.js:33317:16)
    at InjectableAnimationEngine.DomAnimationEngine.animateTransition (http://0.0.0.0:4200/vendor.bundle.js:33232:14)
    at InjectableAnimationEngine.DomAnimationEngine.setProperty (http://0.0.0.0:4200/vendor.bundle.js:33103:18)
    at AnimationRenderer.setProperty (http://0.0.0.0:4200/vendor.bundle.js:66773:26)
    at DebugRenderer2.setProperty (http://0.0.0.0:4200/vendor.bundle.js:13520:23)
    at setElementProperty (http://0.0.0.0:4200/vendor.bundle.js:9797:19)
    at checkAndUpdateElementValue (http://0.0.0.0:4200/vendor.bundle.js:9716:13)
    at checkAndUpdateElementInline (http://0.0.0.0:4200/vendor.bundle.js:9650:24)
    at checkAndUpdateNodeInline (http://0.0.0.0:4200/vendor.bundle.js:12341:23)
    at checkAndUpdateNode (http://0.0.0.0:4200/vendor.bundle.js:12316:16)
    at debugCheckAndUpdateNode (http://0.0.0.0:4200/vendor.bundle.js:12945:59)
    at debugCheckRenderNodeFn (http://0.0.0.0:4200/vendor.bundle.js:12924:13)
```

after a second animation is invoked while a prior animation is still in progress using @angular/animations 4.0.2. if i let the first animation finish, the above error does not happen. how should i go about debugging this?

this was working in @angular 2.0.

EDIT: this seems to be this issue https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/16470